# React design question to load third party javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering

I am new to UI development.So just had design question and wanted to get some thoughts if the approach I am taking is correct.

**Use Case:** I have to conditionally load a **large** third party Marketing JS file. And then use this JS API's in 2 of my components.

**Design I have:**

1. Create Provider Component just to load this JS file and isScriptLoaded state to capture if it's 'loaded' or 'failed'.
   NOTE: There could be more props besides isScriptLoaded in future that I might need to flow down to children.
2. Create a *render less i.e.render => (return null)*  **Child-1** Component that would just make an API call if isScriptLoaded is 'loaded' to redirect the page based on response.
3. Create **Child-2** Component that would just make an API call if isScriptLoaded is 'loaded' , to load dynamic content on current page.

Does above design look ok ?

**NOTE:** I cannot lazy load as it's recommended by vendor to load script right in the beginning to avoid bad user experience.

Thanks!

Comment: i think you can use this: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy to load the "heavy" component file only when you need it

Comment: Thanks @coglialoro for quick response. I made a note above as to why i can't lazy load. I have to conditionally load the script, but if i do, it should be synchronous.